# Why is "? extends" required here in the type declaration

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I noticed that this Java 17 code snippet doesn't compile.

```java
class Foo<T> {
    public Optional<T> getSomeOptional() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

class Bar {
    List<Foo<?>> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
    void bar() {
        List<Optional<?>> list = fooList.stream().map(Foo::getSomeOptional).toList();
    }
}
```

but changing class Bar to this works.

```java
class Bar {
    List<Foo<?>> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
    void bar() {
        List<? extends Optional<?>> list = fooList.stream().map(Foo::getSomeOptional).toList();
    }
}
```

Why is `? extends` required here in the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers don't always infer types of complex expressions correctly. In this case, it may help to break them into parts. E.g. in your case, this works:

```
void bar() {
    Stream<Optional<?>> stream = fooList.stream().map(Foo::getSomeOptional);
    List<Optional<?>> list = stream.toList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this behavior conforms to some specs or is implementation dependent?

Comment: No, I don't. I'd expect the Java language spec to allow it, but I haven't checked

Answer (score 0):

The type guessed by type inference (i.e. when you call a generic method without a type witness) is not always what you want. I think here what happened is that `Foo::getSomeOptional` takes a `Foo<T>` and returns an `Optional<T>`, so the compiler tries to "capture" the wildcard from `Foo<?>` into an unnamed type variable, so it thinks the result is `Optional<some capture>`. So you get `List<Optional<some capture>>`, rather than `List<Optional<?>>`. Although `Optional<some capture>` is a subtype of `Optional<?>`, `List<Optional<some capture>>` is not a subtype of `List<Optional<?>>`, since generics are invariant.

If you add the following type witness to tell it that you want `Optional<?>` (with the plain wildcard) as the result type, it should compile:

```
List<Optional<?>> list =
    fooList.stream().<Optional<?>>map(Foo::getSomeOptional).toList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This thing you have used is called wildcards.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcards-in-java/

Because of Java Type Erasure in the Compile Time, if we don't use a type for our generics then it is considered from the object type, so we use "?" sign or wildcards, by this we basically say that if we pass something in the declaration instead of ?, the compiler should bound the generic to that and don't make it object type.

Note: if you don't bound with anything no matter what type you use, because of java Erasure it's type will become it's super class(the top one).